# Why recyclerview design showing different alignment of view in different row android?

Tags: android, layout

[image]

This is how recyclerview is showing. Different alignment is showing in different rows. I am facing a alignment problem of views in recyclerView item rows.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCompleted"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llReviewNow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFA80D"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Review Now"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llViewVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFA80D"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="View Vendor"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I am facing problem with this two linearlayout. how can this happen same view showing different position in different row?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: sure, i am try to provide screen shot.

Comment: You provided screenshot but removed the layout code. Add the code for layout that you're recycling.

Comment: Is that imageview?

Comment: It's textView in LinearLayout @Prince